# How to use a custom dark theme on Octave?

Tags: linux, octave, octave-gui

I use Mx-Linux btw.
I tried many ways to make sure that octave was using black background and white text instead of the default setting, but no what what I tried I wasn't able to change the editor configuration(I was able to easily change the command prompt to "dark mode").

So I downloaded this(https://github.com/SergioSoldado/octave-color-scheme)  and after unzipping I found that I should move the file qt-settings(without any extension) to a folder

> /home/richard/.config/octave/qt-settings/

But when I opened .config, there was no folder named qt-settings thus I created one and I moved the qt-settings file which was in the Octave-color-scheme-master folder(from github). But this didn't work. Nothing changed. What should I do to make octave dark.

Answer (score 0):

You can install kvantum manager and install a theme. It'll show up in octave.